# php error in using exec function

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to call an .exe program from the web server. I install the wamp package in my computer, which includes Apache:2.4.9, PHP:5.5.12. I succeed in running the php file in the command line to run .exe file.

```
C:\AppServ\www>php julia.php
finished!
```

But when I run the php file in the web server through my browser. It failed. Then I just add `'2>&1'` to my code to find the problem. 
My code in php file is:

```
<?php
exec ('julia  C:\wamp\www\12.jl 2>&1',$output,$status);
echo '$output: <br/>';
print_r ($output);
echo '<br/>';
echo "finished!";
?>
```

And I get the response like this:

```
$output:
Array ( [0]=> ERROR: key not found: "HOMEPATH" [1]=>)
finished!
```

I am new to php. I just cannot figure out what the error is and how to fix the error. Can someone tell me how to fix the error? 
Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: is your web server windows?

Comment: This may help - there's a section towards the end about setting variables like HOMEPATH http://willbradley.name/2013/04/02/troubleshooting-phps-exec-or-shell_exec-on-windows/

Comment: Yes, it's under the windows 7 envrionment.